# How do I force a wait in the C# async await model

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, maui

I think I must be missing something with my understanding of the async await model. What should be a simple thing seems to be unbelievably hard to achieve.

I have a UI which needs to check if the user is logged in. To do this I need to call a method in one of my classes which does some queries.

This class in turn calls 3rd party code which only has async methods.

How can I call that async method and make the application wait until I get a result?

I have tried all the things suggested such as `ConfigureAwait`, `RunSynchronous`, `.Result`, etc.. Nothing seems to reliably work.

It seems so stupid that something like this is so difficult so I assume I am missing a key piece of information.

Thanks.

Comment: We will need to see some code but did you use `await`? Is everything `async` all the way down?

Comment: Ultimately, "you don't" - the idea is that you *await* it, and thereby respond to the asynchronous completion, *without* a synchronous block

Comment: You say you want *the application* to wait, but do you really? Hopefully you mean that you want *code after the method call* to not be called until the async method is done. That is very easy to do: `await`. That's all. That didn't work for you? Then you tried to start the sequence of calls *without being in an async context*. Try `Task.Run(async () => { ... await SomeAsyncMethod(); ...CODE HERE RUNS AFTER SomeASyncMethod RETURNS  });`. IMPORTANT: Code after the whole Task.Run block does NOT wait. Don't try to find a way around it; work with it, as answers describe.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem is the app proceeds to load the main page, which I don't want loaded if the user isn't logged in, so I need to call a query first then decide what page to load. I have tried all the above and each doesn't work for a different reason. Sounds like I am probably approaching this wrong but I just find it annoying that as soon as something is marked as async these simple things get hard to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets make something clear:

> "make the application wait until I get a result?"

Has nothing to do (I cannot stress this enough) with blocking, awaiting or any result whatsoever.

If you are used of making the UI lock until something is done, you should switch your design, instead of trying to find a way to accomplish it.
(I have spent fair amount of time writing MFC apps for Windows Mobile, I used to do this as well)

The correct way to handle such situation, is to let the user know, that there is work being done (Some sort of Activity Indicator for example), and at the same time, make sure that no other code can be executed due to User Input (CanExecute property of your Command for example). When it is appropriate, you can put Cancelation logic.

Even more, in the context of MAUI (and mobile development in general), blocking the UI thread, even for few seconds, is totally not acceptable. It should remain responsive at all times. This is not a matter of choice.

Comment: ^ This is the way. Since you're using a data binding platform, you can use a "notify task" similar to [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand where you are coming from but here is my situation. The app main page is set to Page1. On load, I need to check if the user in the cache is valid - if not then I need to redirect to the login page. The problem is, by the time my code has executed, the app has already loaded Page1. So I actually need the app to wait until the query executes. The checking code is in App.xaml.cs. I need to call async methods since there is an async call further down.

Comment: @BuckBuchanan you can make hundreds of different designs choices. You can make the app go to login, check if the user is logged in anyway, and then redirect to main page. (This is what I usually do). You can make another loading page, that will redirect to Page1 or Login and its sole purpose will be checking stuff and displaying activity indicator. You can make Page1, but instead of showing the content of the page, you can display temporal "empty view" that will be replaced when everything is checked. What you can not do, by any means, is to block the UI thread. Give up on that.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll adjust my thinking!